# How to use a random letter in this JavaScript animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am working on [this animation](http://synaptik.heliohost.org/animateName/), where when hovering over the text, it animates in a beautiful manner.

But I want a change in this animation. I want to use a random character instead of circle *e.g. a unicode birthday cake symbol*.

The problem is I can't find the definition of `circle` anywhere in the `bubbles.js` file, looks like it `circle` is defined somewhere inside jQuery file.

Comment: Please put the code relevant to your question, right into the question, not only on an external link.

Comment: Look `var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];` in main.js

Comment: What are you looking for a definition of?  A `circle` function?  variable?  string?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to replace `circle` with what I want. i.e. a birthday cake

Comment: Until you point to exactly what `circle` you are referring to in the code, we can't help you.  Which line of code is it?  I see two lines with a string `"circle"`string in it.  That's all I can find.  Is that it?  Or what else?

Comment: It must be the line number `200` of `bubbles.js` file. The line which defines the `bubbleShape`.

Comment: check out `this.draw` starting on line 116.  this is where the bubbles (or circles) are defined

Comment: Look for the line `this.draw = function (bubbleShape, dx, dy) {`. That is the function that draws the circle (or square).

Comment: Making cake on a 2D canvas is too hard. Any chances of simply using a unicode char?

Comment: You have to have a font that supports that character, but you could try `ctx.font = '40pt Symbola'; ctx.fillText('', this.curPos.x + dx, this.curPos.y + dy);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bubbles.js, the shapes are drawn in the function that starts with the line:

```
this.draw = function (bubbleShape, dx, dy) {
```

Here is [an article](http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5338643d9c4e9dd03e006f6f?locale_code=fr) that shows how to add triangles and hearts.

If you want to draw a character, you have to reference a font that supports that character, and the browser would have to have that font.

You could try:

```
ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
ctx.font = '40pt Symbola';
ctx.fillText('', this.curPos.x + dx, this.curPos.y + dy);
```

You might be better off creating an image of a birthday cake, and then drawing the image:

Comment: I wanted to use `font-face` css property to import and define font on the web to cancel the chance of user not having the proper font, but [doing this](http://pastebin.com/C1sbYSB8) in CSS file and [this](http://pastebin.com/dkw5HAWq) in JavaScript file doesn't renders the webfont. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SantoshKumar - You might be running into the _same domain restriction_, which means you have to copy the font file to your domain and serve it from there.